# case statement not behaving as expected (fuzzytime() function)

Tags: shell-script, function, case

```
FuzzyTime()
{
local tmp=$( date +%H )

case $((10#$tmp)) in
    [00-05] )
        wtstr="why don't you go to bed"
        ;;
    [06-09] )
        wtstr="I see your very eager to start the day"
        ;;
    [10-12] )
        wtstr="and a very good day too you"
        ;;
    [13-18] )
        wtstr="Good Afternoon"
        ;;
    [19-21] )
        wtstr="Good Evening"
        ;;
    [22-23] )
        wtstr="it is getting late, it's time to party or go to bed"
        ;;
    *)
        wtstr="guess the planet your on has more than a 24 hour rotation"
        echo 'case value is:' $tmp
        ;;
esac
}
```

The case variable represent hours in a 24-hour context, however it seems numbers 08 and 17 cause an issue. I resolved the 08 by using `$((10#$tmp))` but now 17 is an issue; any advice? This is my first bash script ever so sorry in advance if this is a silly question.

Comment: Have you tried running the various commands on the command line and see what output they produce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` denotes character ranges:
[10-12] means digits 1 2 and the range between digits 0-1 -- this will match a single digit in range `0-2`.

Use simple comparisons with `if-elif-else-fi`:

```
if [ "$tmp" -ge 0 ] && [ "$tmp" -le 5 ]; then
  echo "<0,5>"
elif [ "$tmp" -ge 6 ] && [ "$tmp" -le 9 ]; then
  echo "<6,9>"
  #...
else
  #...
fi
```

(Or you could iterate over an array of range limits if you want every interval, but you might as well hardcode it in this case--as you are trying to do).

**Edit: requested array version:**

```
FuzzyTime(){
  local needle=$1 #needle is $1
  : ${needle:=$( date +%H )} #if no needle is empty, set it to "$(date +%H)
  local times=( 0 6 10 13 19 22 24 0 ) 
  local strings=( 
          "why don't you go to bed"
          "I see your very eager to start the day"
          "and a very good day too you"
          "Good Afternoon"
          "Good Evening"
          "it is getting late, it's time to party or go to bed"
          "guess the planet your on has more than a 24 hour rotation"
          )
    local b=0
    # length(times) - 2 ==  index of the penultimate element 
    local B="$((${#times[@]}-2))" 
    for((; b<B; b++)); do
      if ((needle >= times[b] && needle < times[b+1])); then break; fi
    done
  echo "${strings[$b]}"
}

FuzzyTime "$1"
```

**test:**

```
$ for t in {0..27}; do FuzzyTime "$t"; done
0 -- why don't you go to bed
1 -- why don't you go to bed
2 -- why don't you go to bed
3 -- why don't you go to bed
4 -- why don't you go to bed
5 -- why don't you go to bed
6 -- I see your very eager to start the day
7 -- I see your very eager to start the day
8 -- I see your very eager to start the day
9 -- I see your very eager to start the day
10 -- and a very good day too you
11 -- and a very good day too you
12 -- and a very good day too you
13 -- Good Afternoon
14 -- Good Afternoon
15 -- Good Afternoon
16 -- Good Afternoon
17 -- Good Afternoon
18 -- Good Afternoon
19 -- Good Evening
20 -- Good Evening
21 -- Good Evening
22 -- it is getting late, it's time to party or go to bed
23 -- it is getting late, it's time to party or go to bed
24 -- guess the planet your on has more than a 24 hour rotation
25 -- guess the planet your on has more than a 24 hour rotation
26 -- guess the planet your on has more than a 24 hour rotation
27 -- guess the planet your on has more than a 24 hour rotation
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution you presented, I would be very interested in seeing what the array solution looks like, a far more elegant solution I feel if I can't use a case scenario, wold this be out of order to ask for.

Comment: @PeterAtkin Added.

Comment: Amazing , I was no even aware Bash could do this, thank yo so much looks like I'm going to be investing my time into bash, I thought I end up using python but bash it is.. again thank you for your help and elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
[root@localhost ~]# FuzzyTime
-bash: ((: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
-bash: ((: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
-bash: ((: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
-bash: ((: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09") 
-bash: ((: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
-bash: ((: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09"
guess the planet your on has more than a 24 hour rotation

[root@localhost ~]# FuzzyTime 9
I see your very eager to start the day
```

the temp solution seems to be:

```
user=$( whoami ) 
ltime=$( date +%H%M )
new=$(echo $( date +%H ) | sed 's/^0*//')
outputFT=$(FuzzyTime $new)

echo 'Hello '$user 'its' $ltime 'hours,' $outputFT
# echo 'Hello '$user 'its' $ltime 'hours,' $FuzzyTime
```

My problem seems to revolve around getting an automated way of putting in the time in a format BASH system likes, seems any single digit number courses the above error 0-9. (still really love the array solution).

Comment: `new="$(date +%H| sed 's/^0*//')"` is a good way to handle it. If you're absolutely after performance you can do ` new=$(date +%H); new=${new#0}` which will strip a leading zero (if it exists) in-process.

Answer (score 0):

bash/dash/ksh/zsh etc use the same matching rule for `case` patterns as it does for pathname expansion or filename globbing, so your shell is interpreting those patterns as ranges (and the ranges aren't even valid).

`case` also allows you to separate multiple patterns with `|`.

Try `0[0-5])`, `0[6-9])`, `1[0-2])`, etc in your case pattern matches instead.

e.g. like this:

```sh
case $((10#$tmp)) in
    0[0-5]) wtstr="why don't you go to bed" ;;
    0[6-9]) wtstr="I see you're very eager to start the day" ;;
    1[0-2]) wtstr="and a very good day too you" ;;
    1[3-8]) wtstr="Good Afternoon" ;;
    19|2[01]) wtstr="Good Evening" ;;
    2[23]) wtstr="it is getting late, it's time to party or go to bed" ;;
    *) wtstr="guess the planet your on has more than a 24 hour rotation"
       echo 'case value is:' $tmp
       ;;
esac
```